# Change the value of the Checkbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I add a new line of data into the table through the form. On the form I also have checkbox which is also integrated into the table.  Ticking the checkbox leads to getting a value of -1. Is it possible to change -1 into a user defined value such as 'x'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

More complex answer: You can use a hidden bound field, an unbound checkbox, VBA and default values to make a checkbox that behaves just like a bound checkbox that returns a different value.

Consider two fields, `myUnboundCheckbox` and `myBoundTextfield`. `myBoundTextfield` holds `"X"` for `True`, `"Y"` for `False`.
`myUnboundCheckbox` is an unbound checkbox, `myBoundTextfield` is a hidden bound text field

Then you can use the following:

```
Private Sub myUnboundCheckbox_AfterUpdate()
    If myUnboundCheckbox Then
        myBoundTextfield = "X"
    Else
        myBoundTextfield = "Y"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    myUnboundCheckbox = myBoundTextfield = "X"
End Sub
```

Comment: Then please mark the answer as the correct one, and vote as you see fit